# How do I copy artifacts from one jenkins matrix to another?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Currently there is a giant matrix of jobs(A). I am trying to make another one that is smaller(B). I need the artifacts to copy from matrix A into matrix B. Both matrices are set up as listing different testbeds on the x axis and listing python code suites on the y axis.

I have tried to do what Jenkins has told me i.e using a parameter to select the matching configuration to the source project MyMatrixJob/jdk=$jdk. Currently the last format I tried is ${Triggered_build_number_myproject,myproject/param1=$param1}